# Retrofit: Image Upload in POST @body

Tags: image, post, upload, retrofit, wcf-rest

After hours goolging and trying different solutions I gave up and I'm asking for some direction, if possible some example. Here is the problem: I have a class that have a picture atribute. I'm using Retrofit and I want to send the Image as part of the Body of HTTP POST and I'm receiving a error. Bellow the code and the error.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**The POJO Class:**

```
public class Class1 {

@SerializedName("Picture")
private Bitmap mPicture;

@SerializedName("Giver")
public Integer mGiver;

public String getPicture() {
    return mPicture;
}

public void setPicture (Bitmap picture) {
    this.mPicture = picture;
}

public String getLaboratory() {
    return mLaboratory;
}

public void setLaboratory(String laboratory) {
    this.mLaboratory = laboratory;
}
```

**The Activity:**

```
    mClass1.setPicture(mImageBitmap);
    mClass1DAO.insertClass1(mClass1, new Callback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Integer uid, Response response) {
            mClass1.setUID(uid);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.msgThankYou, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dispatchNavigationDrawerActivity();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            showErrorDialog(error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
```

**The API**

```
@POST("/Service.svc/Insert")
void insert(@Body Class1 class1, Callback<Integer> cb);
```

**The WebService in c#**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "InsertMedicineToDonate")]
    Int32 insertMedicineToDonate(MedicineToDonate medicineToDonate);

    //insertMedicineToDonate
    public Int32 insertMedicineToDonate(MedicineToDonate medicineToDonate)
    {
        UserService mUserService = new UserService();

        if (mUserService.isUserAuthorized())
        {
            return this.insertMedicineToDonateAuth(medicineToDonate);

        }
        else
        {
            errorDetail = new CustomHttpError(003);
            throw new WebFaultException<CustomHttpError>(errorDetail, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

    }
```

**Web Service POJO Class**

```
    namespace DoarMed
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MedicineToDonate
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Int32 UID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Bitmap Picture { get; set; }
```

**THE ERROR**

In the debug when I open the class and look at the attributes all of them are correct but the Picture is wrong.

See the Picture information bellow:

```
-       Picture {System.Drawing.Bitmap} System.Drawing.Bitmap
+       Flags   '((System.Drawing.Image)(medicineToDonate.Picture)).Flags' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'    int {System.ArgumentException}
+       FrameDimensionsList '((System.Drawing.Image)(medicineToDonate.Picture)).FrameDimensionsList' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'  System.Guid[] {System.ArgumentException}
+       Height  '((System.Drawing.Image)(medicineToDonate.Picture)).Height' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'   int {System.ArgumentException}
```

and so on

When I try to save the Picture to the DataBase the code throw System.ArgumentException

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, after 3 days trying. I hope it can save your time. if it does save your time, please give me +1.

**Client Android**

**Class**

```
public class MedicineToDonate {
@SerializedName("Picture")
private String mPicture;
@SerializedName("DateTimeInsert")
public Long mDateTimeInsert;

public Bitmap getPicture() {
    return Global.convertStringToBitmap(mPicture);
}

public void setPicture(Bitmap picture) {
    this.mPicture = Global.convertBitmapToString(picture);
}
```

**Retrofit**

```
    mMedicineToDonateDAO.getGiverAllMedicineToDonate(mGlobal.getUserUID(), new Callback<List<MedicineToDonate>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<MedicineToDonate> mMedicineToDonateList, Response response) {
            if (mMedicineToDonateList != null) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= mMedicineToDonateList.size(); i++) {
                    mMedicineToDonate = mMedicineToDonateList.get(i - 1);
                    mAdapter.add(mMedicineToDonate);
                }
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Fragment mFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Global.OPTION_DONATE);
            FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(mFragment)
                    .attach(mFragment)
                    .commit();
            mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            showErrorDialog(error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
```

**Global**

```
    public static String convertBitmapToString(Bitmap imageBitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if(imageBitmap != null) {
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.URL_SAFE);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

public static Bitmap convertStringToBitmap (String encodedString) {
    try {
        byte[] data = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Server Side (C#/IIS/Postgresql)**

```
Class
    [DataContract]
    public class MedicineToDonate
    {
    [DataMember]
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 DateTimeInsert { get; set; }
    [DataMember]

INSERT:
            NpgsqlParameter addPictureParameter = new NpgsqlParameter("@" + Global.MEDICINETODONATE_COL_picture, NpgsqlDbType.Bytea);
        byte[] byteArrayPicture = Global.convertStringToByteArray(medicineToDonate.Picture);
        addPictureParameter.Value = byteArrayPicture;

SELECT:
        byte [] pictureByteArray = (byte[]) reader[12];
mMedicineToDonate.Picture = Global.convertByteArrayToString(pictureByteArray);
```

**Global**

```
    public static string convertByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
```